# Where can I find a description of plan nodes?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working my way through a postgres query plan for the first time.

I'm having some trouble because I don't seem to be able to find any documentation that describes what each of the plan nodes are.  In many cases, the name provides me with a reasonable guess, but in several the name of the plan node is too generic for me to have confidence in it.

Where can I find a list of types of plan nodes, with descriptions of each?

Answer (score 3):

Chapter "[56.1. Row Estimation Examples](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/row-estimation-examples.html)" explaines a lot, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Frank's answer, you might also want to peek at:

http://explain.depesz.com/

It reformats the plans in a more readable manner.